Programming a toaster (memory usage nicely displayed) in C Programming
QUESTION:
You are programming a toaster! The toaster does not have a lot of memory, so you need to be careful about the data types you use (remember that different data types use different amounts of memory). To make this easier, you'd like an easy way to track how much memory your variables are going to use.
Your job is to write a program that shows, in human-readable form (see below for specifics), how much memory a set of variables of a certain type will use. Your program should read a character that identifies the data type ('i' for int, 's' for short, 'c' for char, 'd' for double). Next it should read an integer that indicates how many variables of the given type you wish to store.
Your program should then calculate the amount of memory required to store the given variables. Your program needs to be written in such a way that it would also perform correctly on other computers. In other words, rather than hard-coding specific sizes for the different variable types, your program needs to use the "sizeof()" function to determine how much memory an individual variable of a given type needs.
Finally, you need to output the amount of space required by your variables to the screen. You need to make sure you provide this output in a form that is easy to read for humans. The following examples illustrate what this means:
Examples:
If the user input were:
i 36794
then the amount of space needed (if we assume that an integer uses 4 bytes in memory) would be 4*36794 = 147176 bytes. This corresponds to 147 kilobytes and 176 bytes, so the output should be:
147 KB and 176 B
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char dataType;
    int count;
    
    // Read data type and count of variables
    scanf("%c %d", &dataType, &count);
    
    // Calculate memory size based on data type
    size_t size;
    switch(dataType) {
        case 'i':
            size = sizeof(int);
            break;
        case 's':
            size = sizeof(short);
            break;
        case 'c':
            size = sizeof(char);
            break;
        case 'd':
            size = sizeof(double);
            break;
        default:
            printf("Invalid data type.\n");
            return 1;
    }
    
    // Calculate total memory required
    size_t totalMemory = size * count;
    
    // Convert total memory into kilobytes and bytes
    size_t kilobytes = totalMemory / 1024;
    size_t remainingBytes = totalMemory % 1024;  // Corrected this line
    
    // Output the result
    printf("%zu KB and %zu B.\n", kilobytes, remainingBytes);
    
    return 0;
}


Error message:
Your program displayed :
143 KB and 744 B.
While the expected answer was :
147 KB and 176 B
WHAT IS THE ERROR IN MY CODE? PLEASE HELP

If you read the description more carefully, you might notice that whoever wrote it considers one kilobyte to be 1000 bytes.

Programming a toaster is WILD

147176 Bytes = 147.2 KB = 143.7 KiB

1 KB = 1000 Bytes
1 KiB = 1024 Bytes

So everything seems correct.
See this wikipedia page.
